# How can I share class libraries with Play 2.0?

Tags: playframework-2.0

I have some code that is common across several projects, so naturally, I'd like to have my Play web application and all of my other projects reference this code by source.

I can't seem to figure out how this is done in Play 2.0. I've made this class library into a Maven project, installed it locally, and had the Play application reference it as a dependency, but I get a <strike>run-time</strike> compilation error where one of the shared packages isn't found. If I copy the class library .jar into my Play /lib folder, everything works as expected, but during these early stages of development, I need this to be automated.

What's the best way to have a local class library as a dependency in Play 2.0?

edit: My local maven repository is defined in Build.scala, as follows

```
    val main = PlayProject(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, mainLang = JAVA).settings(

        resolvers += "Local Maven Repository" at "file:///"+Path.userHome.absolutePath+"/.m2/repository"

    )
```

If I run `play dependencies`, Play does indeed find my local Maven package, but I still get the compilation error (package from shared lib not found). Even if this did work though, it's still not ideal because I have to run `maven install` on my shared library every time I change it. This would be better than having to copy my .jar to all of the dependent projects, though.

Comment: how are you defining the dependency, and were is that file stored?

Comment: See edit. Even if this did work though, are you aware of any other way to use shared libs in Play?

Comment: If sbt finds the package, it should work. Besides adding it to the lib folder, I'm not aware of any other way. What error do you get on compilation? Stacktrace?

Comment: `error: package com.sample.lib does not exist` followed by `error: cannot find symbol` when referencing a class from this library.

Comment: not sure why this is happening to you, given the details you provide, it should work... :(

Comment: Ok, well thanks for the help, anyhow. I'll fiddle with it for a while longer and see what I can do

Comment: Could be more of a packaging issue than a Play issue. Can you see if you can load the package in an application that uses Maven in a more classical sense, e.g. the pom.xml of a sample Spring MVC application? I suspect that that would not work either, which would indicate this issue is with Maven and not Play.